# Azure B2C token information

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm a support engineer from Microsoft and I'm assisting my customer on the following case.

The customer has setup B2C authentication for his app, he is reaching out to a private API to get additional claim information for the id token. Once the page is reloaded, the custom claim is gone but not the user's information.
https://www.loom.com/share/2338fbec04f644cdaff82b84eaa84efe

We understand that this is a problem with the SSO behavior set on the app keeping the user signed in so the second tab does not pass through the sign in flow, but I would like to know why the claims from the user attributes like given name and surname are kept, but the claim from the API is gone.

The API claim is retrieved upon successful login in the orchestration step 1.

Answer (score 0):

The User information claims are returned in the token so the user claims will be held till the logout. The claims which you received from the API are not attached to the token, these claims are not persistence.

What you can do here is you can use a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview) to [add a step in your authentication flow to call a API](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange) to obtain the claim and include it in the token.